# Scanners and class

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor, java.util.scanner

We are doing classes, constructors and methods in class at the moment and I get the basics. Leap forward to 2 in the morning and 4 hours of searching on the net for a solution to my question and I am back at Stack Overflow looking for advice.

I have built my class and in it I have my get and sets:

```
 public class staff 
     {
        private String empName;
        private int prefix;
        private int dialCode;
        private int telNum;
        private double grossSalary;


    public staff( String name, int prefix1, int dial, int celNum, double salary)
     {
        empName = name;
        prefix = prefix1;
        dialCode = dial;
        telNum = celNum;
        grossSalary = salary;
    }
```

The next part is where I am getting confused. I am now trying to populate this all using a Scanner but I am getting an error. As always I am not looking for an out right answer but more a nudge in the right direction. Here is the second part to my code.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class staffInfo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String staffName  [] = new String [4];
        int staffPrefix   [] = new int    [4];
        int staffDialCode [] = new int    [4];
        int staffCellNum  [] = new int    [4];
        double staffSalary[] = new double [4];

        int i = 0, j = 0;

        for(j = 0; j < staffName.length; j++)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < staffName.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter staff name and press return : ");
                staffName [i] = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Please enter there cell number prefix : ");
                staffPrefix [i] = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Please enter dialing code : ");
                staffDialCode[i] = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Please enter cell number : ");
                staffCellNum[i] = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Please enter there salary : ");
                staffSalary[i] = input.nextDouble();
            }
            staff staff[j] = new staff(staffName,staffPrefix,staffDialCode,staffCellNum,staffSalary);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: *" Leap forward to 2am in the morning ....Thanks in advance for any help you may offer me."*  - Advice: go to bed.

Comment: Which error do you get? please add it to your post.

Comment: Was in bed for a while Stephen but the problem is keeping me awake. Thanks for the advice none the less.

Comment: *"I am now trying to populate this all using a Scanner but I am getting an error"*  - Advice #2 : if you want people to help you debug your code, you need to explain what your problem is.

Comment: Alexander I am getting the error lines under the staff staff[j] = new staff section and Multiple markers at this line
 - The constructor staff(String[], int[], int[], int[], double[]) is 
  undefined
 - Syntax error on token "j", delete this token
 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from staff to staff[]

Comment: Good .... the first part of @testinfected's answer explains what that means.

Comment: Hopefully that explains what my problem is and yeah Stephen my bad I should have been clearer with my explaination, sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line won't compile.

Look at the arguments you're passing to the constructor of your staff class, do the types match?

Also, you have to separate the declaration of your staff array from the assignation. You did that alright for staffName, staffPrefix, etc.